# cannot find module react/jsx-runtime - when using react 17 with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Example package.json

```json
{
  "name": "react-typescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React and TypeScript example starter project",
  "keywords": [
    "typescript",
    "react",
    "starter"
  ],
  "main": "src/index.tsx",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/error-message": "2.0.1",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "3.0.0",
    "react": "^17",
    "react-dom": "^17",
    "react-hook-form": "6.15.8",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "yup": "1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.9",
    "typescript": "4.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

**Example codesandbox**
https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-colden-j24qf4?file=/src/App.tsx:24-128

Note: My project cannot be upgraded to react 18 at this point due to large codebase dependencies so have to use react 17.

Not to see react type errors on the code

Comment: Can you please include full error/log you are getting?

Comment: Can you try reinstall the node_modules? `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm i`

Comment: @AgainPsychoX - typescript errors in codesandbox link above. The command won't work for codesandbox but it should be a fresh install every time you reload anyway.